# Input from a Art Design Graphic Drawing Tablet

Tags: python, graphics, tkinter, tablet

I have a small, underdeveloped whiteboard application that currently receives input from a mouse using tkinter functions like widget.bind(<'x'>, handler)

Here's the code, if it helps any:

---START CODE---

```
from tkinter import *  # imports required files

canvas_width = 500
canvas_height = 500


def get_width():
    return canvas_width


def get_height():
    return canvas_height


def paint(event):
    color = "black"
    x1, y1 = (event.x - 1), (event.y - 1)
    x2, y2 = (event.x + 1), (event.y + 1)
    w.create_oval(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill=color)




def clear(event):  # experimental helper function
    print('Clearing whiteboard!(Invoked by <Button-3>, a right click.)')
    color = '#FFFFFF'
    w.create_rectangle(0, 0, canvas_width, canvas_height, fill=color)


master = Tk()
master.title("Painting using Ovals")
w = Canvas(master,
           width=canvas_width,
           height=canvas_height)
w.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
w.bind("<Button-3>", clear)
w.bind("<B1-Motion>", paint)

message = Label(master, text="Left-Click and Drag the mouse to draw, Right-click to clear the board")
message.pack(side=BOTTOM)

mainloop()
```

---END CODE---

What I want to know is, if I were to plug a Art Design Graphic Drawing Tablet into my computer, will tkinter still be able to detect clicks? Does pressure on the pad have the same effect as a left click with a mouse? What can be pressed to invoke the equivalent of a right click or movement of the wheel on a mouse on a drawing tablet? I know it's possible for this to vary from program to program, and tablet to tablet, but any information would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are able to use any device to click/drag/scroll on any application on your computer (like this web browser) then it will generate the same events that tkinter will respond to.

if the tablet is not behaving as expected you can bind a generic `<Button>` callback and check which button it was by looking at the event:

```
def callback(event):
    print(event.num)#I have always seen one of (1,2,3,'??')
```